# Prevent multiple logins at the same pc, even from different users

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, authentication, asp-classic

How can I prevent the user login into my website, even if he uses another login?
I can prevent in the same browser, using session/cookies. And also I can prevent the same user, using a DB solution.
But I dont know how to prevent with another browser and/or another user.
Does anyone has any ideas? Im actually using asp and javascript, but im open to another platforms.

Tks,
MC

Comment: Check the login IP address? By no means foolproof but should be sufficient.

Comment: tks, but if the user is in a lan-house, or has two users in the same house, or at work, it wont be enough. I would like to prevent just on the computer.

Comment: You need a combination of cookie and database, that way if a user tries to login from a browser they haven't used before you know and can deal with it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if user have 2 different accounts and uses 2 different computers from LAN(or WiFi on that matter) based network only solution for you is to insert into database open session ID and correlated IP, date time when session got opened.

You also need to make sure that you set open session to 0 once it get closed or just times out.

Session and cookies will help you only to prevent user to use same browser from same computer.

Comment: Nicely regurgitated ;)